# Naming question for functions: implicit or explicit naming of grouping in function name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, naming-convention

Requesting help with **naming** TSQL functions.

### Existing function names (see below for table and relationship descriptions)

I currently have functions named as follows:

- ***CustomerYearsGetByYearRangeOffset***: For each CustomerID, return **all** of their CustomerYears records, over a specified begin/end range
- ***CustomerYearsGetLatestByYearRangeOffset***: For each CustomerID, return their **latest** CustomerYears record, over a specified begin/end range
- ***ObjectRevisionIDsGetByYearRangeOffset***: For each ObjectID, return **all** of their ObjectRevisionIDs records, over a specified begin/end year range
- ***ObjectRevisionIDsGetLatestByYearRangeOffset***: For each ObjectID, return their **latest** ObjectRevisionIDs record, over a specified begin/end year range

Note: All accept a caller-specified begin/end year range offset (relative to the current year). For example, begin/end year offsets -1, 0 would indicate the year one-year prior and the current year.

### Two new functions

The two new functions will implement more sophisticated logic, as follows:

1. For each CustomerID, return their **latest** ObjectRevisionIDs records tied to their **latest** CustomerYears record, over a specified begin/end year range
2. For each CustomerID, return **all** their ObjectRevisionIDs records tied to their **latest** CustomerYears record, over a specified begin/end year range

### What to name the new functions?

Some drafts:

1. ObjectRevisionIDsInLatestYearGetLatestByYearRangeOffset
2. ObjectRevisionIDsInLatestYearGetByYearRangeOffset

**Other ideas?**

Am I thinking about this wrong? For example, abandon the explicit naming approach above and name according to the higher level need it meets?

I see myself calling these new functions frequently, so I prefer to get something that seems "right" each time I use it. ;o)

Thanks for any assistance. Usually when I get this far in writing a question the answer presents itself, but not this time.

---

### Background: tables and relationships

To keep things simple for this question, the database contains four tables (in reality many more tables and fields):

1. Customers (CustomerID)
2. CustomerYears (CustomerID, Year)
3. Objects (ObjectID, CustomerID)
4. ObjectRevisions (ObjectRevisionID, ObjectID, CustomerID, RevisionNumber, Year)

In a nutshell: each year the Customer participates, they get a new record in CustomerYears. In each year, they will have one or more Objects, each of which can have one or more revisions.

For example:

```
Customers (CustomerID)
1
2

CustomerYears (CustomerID, Year)
1|2011
1|2012
2|2012

Objects (ObjectID, CustomerID)
A|1
B|1
C|2

ObjectRevisions (ObjectRevisionID, ObjectID, CustomerID, RevisionNumber, Year)
1|A|1|1|2011
2|A|1|2|2011
3|B|1|1|2011
4|A|1|1|2012
5|B|1|1|2012
6|B|1|2|2012
7|C|2|1|2012
8|C|2|2|2012
```

Comment: Apologies, but I voted to close this as too localized, as naming schemes and related decisions are far too subjective to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your vote; much appreciated. I am of two minds on this--on the one hand, agreed, very localized question. On the other hand, in the process of asking it, it raised a more useful (in my opinion) question of the pros and cons of implicit versus explicit "group by" fields in object names.... So, thank you! If the universe considers it too localized, so be it. : o )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I identified the source of my confusion as well as several solutions:

- My confusion seemed to stem from existing function names *implying* the fields used for grouping
- For example, existing function **ObjectRevisionIDsGetLatestByYearRangeOffset** groups by **ObjectID** *implicitly* over the year range...however, the function could group by **CustomerID** or **CustomerYear** over the year range--the function name leaves this ambiguous
- A rewrite of the existing function name, *explicitly* stating the grouping: **ObjectRevisionIDsGetLatestByObjectOverYearRangeOffset**
- The {BY} clause now explicitly names the grouped fields and the {OVER} clause indicates the function considers a range of years

---

### Solution A

*Explicitly* name the groupings in the new function names:

1. **ObjectRevisionIDsGetLatestByLatestYearByObjectOverYearRangeOffset** (**latest** ObjectRevisionIDs records tied to their **latest** CustomerYears record, over a specified begin/end year range)
2. **ObjectRevisionIDsGetAllByLatestYearByObjectOverYearRangeOffset** (**all** their ObjectRevisionIDs records tied to their **latest** CustomerYears record, over a specified begin/end year range)

### Solution B

Modify existing functions to group by CustomerYear, then by Object--that is, leave the grouping *implicit* but change it to suit the most frequently used business case for the range functions:

1. **ObjectRevisionIDsGetLatestByYearRangeOffset** (modify so existing function groups implicitly by CustomerYear, then by Object, over a specified begin/end year range)
2. **ObjectRevisionIDsGetByYearRangeOffset** (modify so existing function groups implicitly by CustomerYear, then by Object, over a specified begin/end year range)

---

Other solutions potentially exist...still chewing on which path to take.

Answer (score 2):

Where are these functions being called? Are they being called often? How complex is the logic, does it even warrant creating a new database object?

They are very verbose, and the new ones match that style so I guess they're ok. I would prefer to start with Get then I know right away its more of a 'getter' than a subroutine.

I would also pick more terse names, though I have a weakness for clutter free code.

Comment: Thanks Vince. The logic, in this case, does warrant a new object, due to the frequency with which I see them getting used. I call them currently from other queries but they likely will get used from .NET code eventually as well.